# Can I store interfaces in a hash map?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with a rather ugly function in one of my controllers:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/details/{typeLabel}")
    public Optional getDetails(@PathVariable String typeLabel, @RequestParam String id)
            throws NullPointerException {
        Type type = Type.findService(typeLabel);
        switch (type) {
            case BAGS: {
                return bagRepository.findById(new BigInteger(id));
            }
            case BLANKETS: {
                return blanketRepository.findById(new BigInteger(id));
            }
            case HATS: {
                return hatRepository.findById(new BigInteger(id));
            }
            case QUILTS: {
                return quiltRepository.findById(new BigInteger(id));
            }
            default: {
                throw new NullPointerException("Type " + type + "is not recognised, item details could mot be retrieved.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The repositories are all extensions of the PagingAndSortingRepository.  Thanks to the magic of Spring, I can see the interfaces for the repositories, but instantiations seem to be done behind the scenes.

The method shown above works, but it feels a far cry from the Clean Code ideals I am trying to live up to.  The constructor for the controller this method sits in is also frightful, as it needs to list each repository and then assign it to a class variable.  If I were to expand my database to include many other types of item, each with their own repository, it could become very difficult to read and maintain.

I had a similar issue with my services for each of these item types, but managed to whittle it down to something much easier to work with.  The method which used to have a giant switch block now uses a ServiceFinder class to figure out which service to use, depending on the type of item we're working with:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/deletions")
    public Iterable getAllDeleted(@RequestParam String type) {
        // The switch block was here.
        InventoryService service = serviceFinder.findService(type);
        return service.findByDeleteStatus(true);
    }
```

ServiceFinder holds the logic for picking which server to use:

```
public class ServiceFinder {

    private final HashMap<String, InventoryService> services = new HashMap<>();

    public ServiceFinder(BagService bagService, BlanketService blanketService,
                         HatService hatService, QuiltService quiltService) {
        services.put(Type.BAGS.getLabel(), bagService);
        services.put(Type.BLANKETS.getLabel(), blanketService);
        services.put(Type.HATS.getLabel(), hatService);
        services.put(Type.QUILTS.getLabel(), quiltService);
    }

    public InventoryService findService(String typeLabel) throws NullPointerException {
        if (!services.containsKey(typeLabel)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Type " +  typeLabel + " is not recognised.");
        }
        return services.get(typeLabel);
    }

}
```

This all feels much less cumbersome and easier on the eye.  However, when I try to do similar with the repositories it doesn't work.  There are no squiggly warnings or errors in IntelliJ, but my hash map doesn't populate so `findRepositories()` always throws an error :(

```
public class RepositoryFinder {

    private static final HashMap<String, PagingAndSortingRepository> repositories = new HashMap<>();

    public RepositoryFinder(BagRepository bagRepository, BlanketRepository blanketRepository,
                            HatRepository hatRepository, QuiltRepository quiltRepository) {
        repositories.put(Type.BAGS.getLabel(), bagRepository);
        repositories.put(Type.BLANKETS.getLabel(), blanketRepository);
        repositories.put(Type.HATS.getLabel(), hatRepository);
        repositories.put(Type.QUILTS.getLabel(), quiltRepository);
    }

    public static PagingAndSortingRepository findRepository(String typeLabel) throws NullPointerException {
        if (!repositories.containsKey(typeLabel)) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Type " + typeLabel + " is not recognised, item details could mot be retrieved.");
        }
        return repositories.get(typeLabel);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing, what I could try instead, or why what I am aiming for will just never work with interfaces instead of concrete classes?

Comment: can you use Join to fetch based on query? can you move logic to service layer? can you move this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas: I do not understand the first two questions, but I have copied the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com (which I did not know existed until now, so thank you for teaching me something new today :))

Comment: The question got closed in code review, we're back to handling it over here unless you are able to reopen it there on the basis that I do have working code and but am trying to find ways of doing it better.